How to handle existing Rest api callouts for bulk records
We have a rest API callout built in queueable apex to fetch and update HR information of related contact records from external system when contact  gets inserted/updated in Salesforce.
The issue happens when there is bulk insert/update on contact records which will trigger this API call and results in governor limits.
How to bulkify the code or redesign the integration to support this integration .
Please note : the external system doesn't have bulk api .

Take the approach illustrated in this proof of concept.
